# How to drop a task from the Celery queue if connection is lost?

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Celery beat and workers to retrieve the latest news every 30 mins. At night when my computer is asleep the internet connection is lost. Then in the morning the same task wants to run several times to catch up for the lost attempts. How can this tasks not pile up in case the connection is lost?

In the Admin section of Django there's an option called "Expires timedelta with seconds" but it doesn't seem to be doing what I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`max_retries`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#retrying) to 0 or handle the error in the task.  This will prevent any retries.